# How can I select row with oldest date with dql Doctrine querybuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I am trying to compute the average time it takes for users to respond to questions on a Q&A site like SO. I am using Symfony and Doctrine. The following code gives a result, but it's not the result I am looking for. It gives the average for *all* answers, and I would like it to give the average for just the *first* answers.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(q.date)) / COUNT(DISTINCT q.id)')
    ->from(Question::class, 'q')
    ->join('q.answer', 'a')
    ;
return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

I tried throwing in a `MIN()` around `a.date`, but it gave an groupby error.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a join to only the oldest answer per question. You can achieve that using a subquery in your ON clause

```
SELECT AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(answer.date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(question.date)) as avgFirstResponseTime
FROM question
INNER JOIN answer ON answer.id = (
    SELECT id 
    FROM answer 
    WHERE question_id = question.id
    ORDER BY date ASC
    LIMIT 1    
)
```

I'm note sure if this kind of subquery works with doctrines querybuilder or in DQL at all. But you could use `$entityManager->createNativeQuery` if DQL doesn't support it.